# Ok to conceal electrical junction box under cabinet behind removable toe-kick

Tags: electrical, nec

There is a 5 or 6 inch gap between the floor and the bottom of my kitchen cabinets. I have ikea cabinets so the toe kick is connected to the cabinet legs by plastic clips. It comes off just by pulling with a small amount of effort. Would putting an electrical junction box in this area be a violation of electrical code? If I put it there I would mark in the cabinet above it that there is a junction box below so that it would be easy to identify and find.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of readily accessible in the National Electrical Code.

> Accessible, Readily (Readily Accessible). Capable of being reached quickly for operation, renewal, or inspections without requiring those to whom ready access is requisite to actions such as to use tools, to climb over or remove obstacles, or to resort to portable ladders, and so forth

Junction boxes above drop ceilings are considered Accessible but if you have to remove part of the building (such as a piece of drywall) then it is NOT  accessible. I had a house where the panel was behind some paneling that was hinged. This is usually acceptable to the Inspector.

Bottom line is if you can easily access it, and if you leave information as to where to find it, it should fit the definition if Accessible.

Comment: Does the NEC have a different definition of portable ladder than the rest of the world; because a literal reading of that seems to ban most ceiling mounted lighting/etc.  Unless you're significantly taller than average even a ceiling box in a typical residential area is going to need a stool or short step ladder for comfortable access; with cathedral ceilings in homes or the high ceilings in many commercial/industrial buildings needing a large ladder or powered lift to access the boxes used to connect overhead lighting.

Comment: I believe those items are accessible just not readily accessible. Actually junction boxes only have to be accessible whereas circuit breakers and such items would have to be readily accessible. The junction box in the question would be readily accessible and therefore accessible. So it fits both definitions. 

Comment: The code says boxes have to be "*accessible*", not "*Readily Accessible*".  "***Accessible (as applied to wiring methods).** Capable of being removed or exposed without damaging the building structure or finish or not permanently closed in by the structure or finish of the building.*"

Answer (score 2):

Technically it's not concealed as it is accessible once the front panel of the toe kick is removed. So yes it is OK